# Gatsby Dynamic Routing 404 build

Tags: reactjs, react-router, gatsby, react-router-dom, reach-router

I'm building a website with Gatsby and Strapi.
I'm using [dynamic routes](https://www.gatsbyjs.com/docs/how-to/routing/client-only-routes-and-user-authentication/).

With `gatsby develop`, everything fine.

With `gatsby build`, **links between pages are working, but typing the URLs give me 404**.
Example: I can go from `/` to `/room` with a click but when I type `/room`, I get a 404.

**How should I fix this?** Am I missing something?

index.js routing part:

```
        <Router basepath="/">
          <Doors path="/" exitTransition={exitTransition}></Doors>
          <Room path="/room" exitTransition={exitTransition}></Room>
          <Sound path="/sound" sounds={sounds} currentSoundIndex={currentSoundIndex} setCurrentSoundIndex={setCurrentSoundIndex} audioPlayerRef={audioPlayerRef}></Sound>
          <Cloakroom path="/cloakroom" clothes={clothes}></Cloakroom>
          {clothesRoutes}
        </Router>
```

gatsby-node.js

```
exports.onCreatePage = ({ page, actions }) => {
  const { createPage } = actions
  if (page.path === `/`) {
    page.matchPath = `/*`
    createPage(page)
  }
}
```

*Note:* Local http-server build is working. But on my client's hosted server it's not.
I'm using Router from @reach/router.

**Thank you so much for your help!**

Comment: Have you checked the trailing slash? Does it work when trying to reach `/room/`?

Comment: Does not change anything...

Comment: But actually I noticed the problem appears when I upload the site online. Does someone have a hint?

Comment: What server? Self-hosted? Netlify? Vercel? Gatsby cloud? AWS?

Comment: That was on a AlpHosting Apache Server. Got it resolved with a .htaccess!

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I got it resolved.

I simply needed to place an `.htaccess` file in the public directory with that content:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.html$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.html [L]
```

Answer (score 0):

Extending the solution proposed by [@Antbarras](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4030170/antbarras). The `.htaccess` **must not** be placed in the public folder because it's an autogenerated directory that it's overridden in each build so if you place any file there, it will be lost in the next build because the source code doesn't have it.

The way of adding a permanent `.htaccess` in the public folder is through the [static folder](https://www.gatsbyjs.com/docs/how-to/images-and-media/static-folder/), which is a folder that its content it's cloned into the `/public` folder keeping the internal structure. So:

- Create a `/static` folder at the root of the project
- Add the `.htaccess` in the first level